# Xamarin.Forms ListView does not display large number of photos - memory issue

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am building an app with a custom photo gallery. I have a ListView which displays 4 photos in every row. All the photos on the device are first loaded to a list (photos about 100x100), then I have an observable collection with a custom RowItem class which has 4 photos in it, and bound to the ListView.   Everything works fine with up to 100-200 photos, but when there are 1000+ photos the application crashes. I believe it is a memory issue.

Is there a way to implement this correctly so an infinite number of photos can be handled? I an option "on demand load" for ListView, but I am not sure how it is going to unload the previously loaded photos. Also, how it is going to reload them back when the user scrolls up?

Comment: application crashes - how, any exception?

Comment: I am doing a similar project. I end up using OnItemAppearing and OnItemDisappearing overrides on the ViewCell (that is the row you used). That way you can just load the images which are appearing on the list. Couldn't make it work with CachingStrategy=RecycleElement. So how did you solve the issue? I am also having a weird issue, some images does not show up when I ran it on IOS. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods you could try:

- Setting the [ListView CachingStrategy to RecycleElement](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/) may help in reducing the memory usage, by using concepts not too different from virtualization.
- Make sure the image size is downsized to its view size (e.g. do not load 1920x1080 image to a control that's 10x10), as described in [this performance guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#optimizeimages)
- You could further user the FFImageLoading library, as suggested by JayPatel to reduce the memory used by displaying the image effectively.

YMMV so test out different combos to find one that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a problem with ListView and Images. A lot of guys use [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView) to visualize images...

[Here](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/Samples/DLToolkitControlsSamples/SamplesFlowListView) you can find a sample

DataTemplate and DataTemplateSelector support

Fixed or automatic column count

Grouping support

Columns can expand to empty space (configurable)

ANY View can be used as a cell

All Xamarin.Forms platforms supported

Simple sample

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false"
    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
    FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</flv:FlowListView>
```

Comment: did yo use the FlowListView before? how does it manage the memory, that's the most important part for me. Suppose we want to display all photos (1000+) on the device, how does it load and unload the photos to UI?

Comment: @CShark I think you can take a look to GitHub or ask to the author opening an issue

Comment: Is there anybody with experience in custom gallery with xamarin forms help me? I can pay too.